how to merge dfs without duplicate lines
My dataframes are similar to below
df1:
   user  name    length  job
0  5234  Ed      7       manager
1  4793  Mark    14      admin
2  9321  Nick    8       admin
3  8149  Duncan  3       admin
4  3742  John    9       admin
5  7315  Lucy    12      admin
6  6541  Heidi   25      admin

df 2:
   user  name    open  click
0  5234  Ed      3     1
1  4793  Mark    
2  9321  Nick    5     4
3  8149  Duncan  1     0
4  8149  Duncan  2     1
5  3742  John    21    3   
6  6541  Heidi   7     2

my desired outcome is:
   user  name    length  job      open click
0  5234  Ed      7       manager  3    1
1  4793  Mark    14      admin    NaN  Nan
2  9321  Nick    8       admin    5    4
3  8149  Duncan  3       admin    3    1
4  3742  John    9       admin    21   3
5  7315  Lucy    12      admin    NaN  NaN
6  6541  Heidi   25      admin    7    2

Currently I am using this code:
df3  = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='user', right_on='user', how='left',
               suffixes=('', '_y')).filter(regex='^(?!.*_y)')

However when I merge them using this code, I end up with duplicate lines for Duncan rather than one single line. How can I achieve this please? I should add that my actualo dfs are several hundred lines long - most merge fine but several are duplicating.

since you have multiple records for Duncan on df2, you need to sum values before merge as:
df2_merged = df2.groupby(['user', 'name'], as_index=False).sum()
print('df2_merged\n',df2_merged)

Output:
    df2_merged
            user    name  open  click
        0  3742    John  21.0    3.0
        1  4793    Mark   0.0    0.0
        2  5234      Ed   3.0    1.0
        3  6541   Heidi   7.0    2.0
        4  8149  Duncan   3.0    1.0
        5  9321    Nick   5.0    4.0

If you do not want to have as floats and if you want to fill NaN's you can also add:
df2_merged['open'] = df2_merged['open'].fillna(0).astype(int)
df2_merged['click'] = df2_merged['click'].fillna(0).astype(int) 

After this pre-step you can merge with df1:
df3=df1.merge(df2_merged,left_on=['user','name'], right_on=['user','name'], how='left')


You can just aggregate the df2 and then merge these two.
df2 = df2.groupby(['user', 'name'], as_index=False).agg({
    'open': 'sum',  
    'click': 'sum'
})

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['user', 'name'], how='left')

which should give you:
   user    name  length      job  open  click
0  5234      Ed       7  manager   3.0    1.0
1  4793    Mark      14    admin   0.0    0.0
2  9321    Nick       8    admin   5.0    4.0
3  8149  Duncan       3    admin   3.0    1.0
4  3742    John       9    admin  21.0    3.0
5  7315    Lucy      12    admin   NaN    NaN
6  6541   Heidi      25    admin   7.0    2.0

